# Are the emails inside the outbox folder stored locally on the machine where the mail was sent

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, smtp, pop3

I'm asking this question because I got curious about an email I'm sending from the office with `Outlook` using the `Delay delivery` option. When I searched for that mail at home to modify it on `Outlook`, I couldn't find it.

Are emails stuck inside the `Outbox` folder (as is the case of a `Delay delivery` email) local to the machine where they were sent? and if possible where are these mail stored physically (`path` to a file)?

Besides, if these emails are stored locally, does it mean that `Outlook` in this case is using `POP` protocol instead of `IMAP` (where emails would be synchronized from a remote server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. For IMAP accounts Outlook stores Outbox locally in .OST cache file. You can find the path to this file in Outlook account options (Data Files tab).

Comment: I guess it's impossible to make this file synchronized between different mail clients on different machines, isn't it?

Comment: You're right again... unfortunately.

Comment: Can I extract ***EMLs*** from _OST file_ (`Draft and Outbox` folder) or convert _OST_  to ***PST file*** ?

Comment: What about in Exchange Mode? Will scheduled e-mails be sent from *non*-IMAP accounts if my laptop is offline?

Answer (score 1):

When unchecking 'Used Cached Exchange Mode' in Outlook 2013 in File>account settings>Data Files tab>settings>advanced tab I found that my mail with Delayed delivery did get synched to the server. I saw it pop up in my outbox in Outlook on another workstation. Ofcouse be aware of any drawbacks unchecking 'Used Cached Exchange Mode'. (I'm still checking which :)